# coloring text in a dcolumn aligned cell of a table

Tags: tables, color, dcolumn

I need to color some text red (not color the cell background) in cell in a table to highlight it.  The numbers in the column are aligned on the decimal using the `dcolumn` package.  The problem is that

```
\color{red}{0.044}
```

doesn't compile  it's saying

```
} inserted at
\color{red}{0.
044}
```

and then saying that there is one too many `}`.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Also, `\color{red}` is a switch and does not take a paraeter, so you could try `\color{red}0.044`.

Comment: @PeterGrill you could _try_ that (it won't work though) Or at least it will only color the first bit.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You just need to copy the definition of the `D` type and add colo(u)r:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color,dcolumn}

\makeatletter
%\newcolumntype{D}[3]{>{\DC@{#1}{#2}{#3}}c<{\DC@end}}

\newcolumntype{E}[4]{>{\color{#1}\DC@{#2}{#3}{#4}}c<{\DC@end}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{E{red}..{-1}}
1.2\\
\multicolumn{1}{E{green}..{-1}}{-11.2}\\
1.333\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd like to define a newcolumn type with one mandatory argument (the number of decimal places) and one optional argument (the text color) it aligns the period in the cell's contents on the decimal in the column.  how would I do that. Also, can I have more than one
\makeatletter
...
\makeatother
blocks

Comment: you can have as many make ... as you want but you only ever need one, you can put ll redefinitions there (or better dont have one at all and put teh definitions in a local package you can reuse)

Comment: newcolumntypes (as defined in array package) don't have optional arguments so you have to make it mandatory, but that;s OK you can just use D or E{red} rather than D and D[red]

Comment: If I use D in the column specification, and E in the multicolumn with the cell I use E with line up on the decimals with the normal D cells in the same column  also would
\newcolumntype{E}[2]{>{\color{#2}\DC{.}{.}{#1}}c<{\DC@end}} 
be valid?

Comment: I'm not sure I can parse that sentence but the answer is probably that yes it will work, the colour version doesn't affect the alignment so if you use the same alignment spec in the multicolumn{1} as in the preamble they will line up, or use the colour one in both with black as the color. yes your E spec looks OK to me except should be `\DC@` not `\DC` (untested)

Comment: Thanks a lot I got it to work (the it is a C++ class that generates pretty LaTeX Tables for autogenerating human readable report from simulation output, the public interface of the C++ class is very simple).  The first "with" was supposed to be a "will".  The question about more than one makeatletter makeatother was because multiple latex generating classes need to define their own special commands, and collecting all the makeatletter makeatothers out of each used class' output for the preamble into a single makeatletter makeatother block would be problematic.